# Gmail POP3 Limit?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have 398 messages in my inbox, but my application which is connecting to gmail's pop3 servers tells me that I have only 250. What's the problem?

Comment: How do you know you have only 250?

Comment: How can we possibly know? we are not a site of psychic software developers.

Comment: @dkarp     Because every email application I use tells me that I have 250.    @Mimisbrunnr I thought that maybe someone had experience with gmail's pop3 server. What could I except from a person living in canada anyway, lol'd.

Comment: The reason I ask is that in GMail's conversation view, the total number of messages listed includes all messages in the conversations even if some of them aren't in the Inbox.  Switching to Inbox message view will give you an accurate count.

Comment: If your Gmail address is pop@gmail.com and this is the only account you have set up in your e-mail client program (i.e. Outlook, Windows Live Mail, Thunderbird, etc.) and you have 398 messages in your inbox in the program, but you see only 250 when you use Gmail webmail, then 250 is what you have. Maybe you have deleted some of the messages you downloaded with the e-mail program. If you want the inbox on Gmail to reflect inbox in e-mail program, you must stop using POP3. Start using IMAP instead!

Comment: I'm in the middle of downloading all old gmails. Pop3 seems to be downloading all the old emails first into my client.

Answer (score 4):

You may have to tell gmail to let you download previously downloaded mail.

[image: Like so]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a Gmail feature. Probably it comes from [Gmail bandwith limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en), which says:

```
Limit               Per day
Download via IMAP   2500 MB
Download via POP    1250 MB
Upload via IMAP     500 MB

Reaching the limit triggers a safeguard that temporarily suspends the account.
```

There is not a word about limiting number of e-mails, but at least it contains a word "limit" :)

From this [blog post](http://tech.kateva.org/2009/02/gmails-undocumented-pop3-download-limit.html) dated back to 2009 we can see it worked like this long time ago:

> ...I can download about 340 messages at a time. I think the limit is in place for a few minutes; I’ve been able to download about 3,000 over 9 or so sessions.

I personally experienced limit of 250-500 emails per connection.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.